# CKeditor skins, good ones and how to build them?

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, ckeditor, skinning

I was wondering if there is a resource of CKeditor skins anywhere? Like a list of downloadble skins. The default one is a little meh.

Also where are the doc's for creating your own skin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am satisfied with ones shipped within library, but if you want to edit existing skin, you must only check what's inside the library directory - you'll find the where skins are easily.

Comment: But the default one is beige. Beige! Your better than that.

Comment: Another sarcasm / irony i don't understand?

Comment: yes, and? i don't know what is wrong with beige color. some like it, some don't. was it all about that?

Comment: yep, sorry about the joke. Beige is just a bit of an out-dated color and is difficult to fit into newer designs. That's all.